# How can I permanently and globally disable Firefox's annoying and useless "leave page" confirmation?

Tags: firefox, user-interface

We have carefully reviewed and considered Mozilla's opinion on the matter and dismissed it as something that does not fit our web browsing requirements. We are seeking community help to find a way to completely, totally, globally, and permanently disable the "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." Stay/Leave dialog box.

Currently this dialog box is annoying our employees in data entry roles as it slows down their work and lowers their wages. We cannot tolerate this program behavior as it is hurting our staff, just so that you understand where we are coming from.

Comment: Have you set `dom.disable_beforeunload` to `true`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to save your employees from underwork.

Such sites hook into the "beforeunload" document event to let you know you have
a draft that you didn't save.
There is a global setting to disable that, but no way to do it on a per-site basis.

- Enter `about:config` in the address bar
- In the search box above the list, type or paste `dom.disable_beforeunload`
- When displayed, double-click this preference to switch the value from "false"
  to "true".

Reference: Mozilla's [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).